# Fetching only distinct data from table using hasura-graphql data provider in react-admin

Tags: graphql, react-admin, hasura

I am working on a project where I have to fetch only distinct data from the table display in the dropdown. How can I do that? I am using '''hasura-graphql''' data-provider for it. So how can I get only distinct data from a particular column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think passing a default "distinct_on" filter with the column name as value will do the job. Also, hasura recommends sorting by this column in first position.

> It is typically recommended to use order_by along with distinct_on to
>   ensure we get predictable results (otherwise any arbitrary row with a
>   distinct value of the column may be returned). Note that the
>   distinct_on column needs to be the first column in the order_by
>   expression.

So i set default sort:

```
<ReferenceInput
    reference="yourTable"
    source="yourDistinctColumn"
    sort={{field: "yourDistinctColumn", order: "ASC"}}//or DESC, your choice
    filter={{distinct_on: "yourDistinctColumn"}}
>
    <SelectInput optionText="yourDistinctColumn"/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/distinct-queries.html

Comment: Thanks for the help but I have to show the data dropdown option for SelectInput. How can we use the filter in ReferenceInput?

Comment: I tried this solution but `filter={{distinct_on: "distinctColumn"}}` is not working properly its throwing error **Can not read property of undefined**. I am new to Hasura and react-admin

Comment: Are you changing `distinctColumn` to the column you need to be distinct?

Comment: yes, this is the piece of my code
`<ReferenceInput
        label="Block"
        reference="location"
        filter={{ distinct_on: "block" }}
      >
        <SelectInput optionText="block" />
      </ReferenceInput>`

Comment: In what file and line the error "Can not read property of undefined" happens?

Comment: Passing `distinct_on` to `filter` turns into `where: {"distinct_on": {"_eq": "distinctColumn"}}`